# list pop() not printing out correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried making a text writing program but the text deleting part doesn't seem to work. It should delete the text, but it just replaces the text with my new input. I am new to python so I would appreciate a simple answer. Here is my code:

```
import os
import msvcrt

lst = []
while True:
    userinput = msvcrt.getch()
    if userinput == "b'\\x08'":  # delete last input
        lst.pop()
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        print("".join(lst))
    elif userinput == "b'\\r'":  # enter key
        lst.append("\n")
    else:
        lst.append(userinput.decode("ASCII")) #normal text
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        print("".join(lst))
```

When I input "Hello" it prints:

```
>Hello
```

then press Backspace, I expect:

```
>Hell
```

but it just stays

```
>Hello
```

And when I press a button after that, e.g. "f" then it prints out:

```
>Hellf
```

Comment: Please provide an example run of your program. What input do you give and what output do you see? And what do you expect instead?

Comment: `userinput == "b'\\x08'"` I think you want `userinput == b"\x08"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're comparing against the serialized representation of the bytes. It will never match.

Instead:

```
if userinput == b'\b':  # delete last input
```

and:

```
elif userinput == b'\r':  # enter key
```

`\b` is the same as `\x08`, but more readable